# Is it possible to Add/Update key under App.xaml in code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am not sure if it is possible what I am trying to achieve.
I am using SettingsFlyout to add Custom Settings for my windows app.
Under Custom Settings, I have 2 text boxes and save button, where an user will input appropriate text and will click save button. When user clicks save button I want to update appropriate keys under  in App.xaml if it is presents, if it is not present I want to add 2 keys under . I want to upadate app.xaml because I want my app to remember users last preference; so that if user terminates the app and comes back after several days, the app load those keys from . Let me know if this is not possible or if you have better idea.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You need only save the keys?
You try to use Settings?

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Key1 = TextBox1.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Key2 = TextBox2.Text;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

like this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a merged dictionary and have a default one and a custom one and try to replace the merged one when the settings change. The problem is - the `StaticResource` bindings in XAML don't update automatically so if any resource is already resolved - you might need to somehow force it to resolve again and that's a bit of a hacky territory.